# Why keyboard keys syntax doesn't appear on editing-help?

Tags: feature-request

Could it be included there?

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: How can a keyboard have syntax?

Comment: Are you talking about the <kbd> tag?

Answer (score 1):

The editing help is about the markdown language.  Keyboard shortcuts are a different thing all together.